# Cannot overwrite CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, overwrite

I have already searched for an answer here and spent a long time on google, but nothing...

I've already tried opening the file with 'w' instead of 'r' or 'a' but I still can't get my code to overwrite the current results I have originally written to the CSV file. I'm basically scraping information from a website and I want to first search for a term, scrape that data, save it to the CSV file AND THEN, search for another term and scrape that data and overwrite the current CSV file with the new data.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request


def getPageSource(current_page):

    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
    req = urllib.request.Request(current_page, headers=hdr)
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib")
    return(soup)


def get_length(file_path):
    with open("data.csv", 'r', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        reader_list = list(reader)
        return len(reader_list)


def write_data(file_path, company_name, role, full_url, date):
    fieldnames = ['ID', 'Company','Role', 'URL', 'Date']
    next_id = get_length(file_path)
    with open(file_path, "w", encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        #writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({
        "ID": next_id,
        "Company": company_name,
        "Role": role,
            "URL": full_url,
                "Date": date
            })
        csvfile.close()



def find_data(source):
    base_url = 'https://www.irishjobs.ie'

    for a in source.find_all(attrs={"itemtype" : "https://schema.org/JobPosting"}):
        job_info = a.find('h2').find('a')
        company_name = a.find('h3').find('a').get_text()
        url = job_info['href']
        full_url = (base_url + url)
        role = (job_info.get_text())
        date = a.find('li',class_='updated-time').get_text().replace('Updated','').strip()
        write_data("data.csv", company_name, role, full_url, date)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    query = input('Enter role to search: ')
    source = getPageSource('https://www.irishjobs.ie/ShowResults.aspx?Keywords='+query+'&Location=102&Category=3&Recruiter=All&SortBy=MostRecent&PerPage=100')

    find_data(source)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'm new to SO and this is valuable information coming from a long time user as you seem to be. I'll edit my question now.

Comment: One last thing: You're using `"a"` mode. That's explicitly asking Python to append to the file instead of overwriting it, so that's not going to be useful. Show the code you tried with "w" mode (and what it did). Or did you _want_ to append? One of your paragraphs talks about "append new data to it", and another one about "overwrite … with the new data". Which one do you want?

Comment: @abarnert, I'm trying to overwrite the file with the new data, not append. I have updated my code and replaced the 'a' with 'w' but I get only one row with one result instead of 100 like I used to get when I was only appending the data.

I originally included all of the code because I thought it would be easier to debug, that's all.

Comment: You are doing overwrite_data for each row.

Comment: @pyrish That's what "overwrite" means. If you replace everything that's there with one row, you'll only have one row. If you don't want that, what _do_ you want? You say it's not "append", but I can't think of any other options. Give us a stripped-down program that we can run, with a very small data set, and tell us what output you actually want vs. what it produces.

Comment: Also, read the [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) link I gave you earlier. It really is helpful in writing a good question.

Comment: You need to open the file once at the start (using `w`). Write all the rows and then close the file at the end. Each time you open with `w` it will erase the file, so you probably only ever see your last entry at the moment.

Comment: It is not possible to show you how to fix your code, as what you have given does not run.

Comment: @MartinEvans, I tried your suggestion and sure enough, it's only saving the last record into the CSV file. I have provided the entire code, I have done this in the beginning but I was told it was not a good practice to post the entire code here in SO and keep things simple. I appreciate your help.

Comment: When writing questions, the aim is to add the minimum amount of code that can still recreate your problem. e.g. just keeping the code for `company_name` rather than all the other elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep the file open until you have finished writing it. Also, it is easier to keep a count of the rows written (using `enumerate()`) than to keep trying to read the file back in:

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request


def getPageSource(current_page):

    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
    req = urllib.request.Request(current_page, headers=hdr)
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    return (BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib"))


def find_data(source):
    base_url = 'https://www.irishjobs.ie'
    fieldnames = ['ID', 'Company','Role', 'URL', 'Date']

    with open('data.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(fieldnames)

        for id, a in enumerate(source.find_all(attrs={"itemtype" : "https://schema.org/JobPosting"}), start=1):
            job_info = a.find('h2').find('a')
            company_name = a.find('h3').find('a').get_text()
            url = job_info['href']
            full_url = (base_url + url)
            role = (job_info.get_text())
            date = a.find('li',class_='updated-time').get_text().replace('Updated','').strip()
            writer.writerow([id, company_name, role, full_url, date])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    query = input('Enter role to search: ')
    source = getPageSource('https://www.irishjobs.ie/ShowResults.aspx?Keywords='+query+'&Location=102&Category=3&Recruiter=All&SortBy=MostRecent&PerPage=100')

    find_data(source)
```

This would give you `data.csv` starting:

```
ID,Company,Role,URL,Date
1,Computer Futures,Xamarin Developer,https://www.irishjobs.ie/Jobs/Xamarin-Developer-8143810.aspx,06/03/2018
2,Wallace Myers International,New Business Development Manager,https://www.irishjobs.ie/Jobs/New-Business-Development-Manager-8143989.aspx,06/03/2018
3,Reperio Human Capital Ltd,Senior Software Developer - Dublin,https://www.irishjobs.ie/Jobs/Senior-Software-Developer-Dublin-8150128.aspx,20/03/2018
```

In your case, it is probably easier to just use a plain `csv.writer()` rather than a `Dictwriter()`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Martin Evans. I will take your advise as well as everyone else input and try to improve my questions. I appreciate you taking the time to correct my code even. Cheers.